# MeteorJS: reactiveDict VS Session?

Tags: meteor

So, I might be missing something, but everyone says ReactiveDict is better than Session when storing instance values. But, what about hashing? It doesn't seem as though reactiveDict can hide data like storing in the Session? I am able to get the data from the app through the console using reactiveDict... so, if I wanted to hide this instance data, wouldn't it make sense to use Session?

Thoughts?

```
appState = new ReactiveDict('appState')...;
Session.set(key, value)...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can see the source code for session package here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/session/session.js

`Session = new ReactiveDict('session');`

Session is nothing but a ReactiveDict.

Reason why people say ReactiveDict is better than session is, Session is global, you can go to console and type `Session.keys` to get all the values.

Where as `ReactiveDict` has option to not make it  global

if you want to use `ReactiveDict` in single file you can use like below

```
const appState = new ReactiveDict('appState')
.
.
.

appState.set('key', 'value');
.
.
.
appState.get('key');
```

here `appState` is not global.

If you want to use same across different files, you can use import and export like below

```
set.js
------

const appState = new ReactiveDict('appState')
appState.set('key', 'value');
.
.
.
export default appState
```

then

```
get.js
------

import appState from './set.js';

appState.get('key'); //result will be value'
```

So the advantage reactivedict has over session is, session is global where as reactivedict can be not global.